# How to center an element with a left and right aligned element on both sides?

Tags: html, css

I've been having an enormous amount of trouble for what I thought would be easy, but it's turning out to be much more difficult than I had anticipated.

I have an image alt="home" that I want to center in my footer, with text underneath it, but margin-left and margin-right: auto don't work, margin: 0 auto doesn't work either. Are there other options to center something?

And for the address, it's being pushed down because the width of the copyright and "home" img have a width the size of the footer. When I try to apply a width percentage to the div containing the home img and the copyright text, it disappears for some reason?

This is the result I want to achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIyLF.jpg

jsfiddle (with complete html and css): http://jsfiddle.net/A2H3n/

If anyone knows what's going on, and can let me know, that would make me so happy... but really, I've spent 4 hours trying to fix this(I've just started learning CSS). Any help would be appreciated!

Relevant HTML:

```
<footer>

    <div id="sociallinks">
        <img class="sociallogo" src="images/facebooklogo.jpg" alt="Facebook">
        <img class="sociallogo" src="images/Twitterlogo.jpg" alt="Twitter">
    </div>

    <div id="logoandtext">  
            <img id="footerlogo" src="images/blackbeltinverse.png" alt="home">
            <p>&copy; Hsien-Jin Martial Arts Studio<p>  
    </div>

    <div id="contactinfo">
        <p>7548 Mahogany Rd</p>
        <p>Los Angeles, CA 97789</p>
        <p>(444) 123-4567 </p>
    </div>


</footer>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
    footer{
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#sociallinks{
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
}

.sociallogo{
    width: 3em;
    height: 3em;

}


#footerlogo {
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

#contactinfo {
    line-height: 1.25em;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`display:inline-block;` may be the answer:

```
footer{
text-align:center;
}

#sociallinks, #logoandtext, #contactinfo{
display:inline-block;
}

#contactinfo{
float:right;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bonatoc/PLbae/1/

CSS overwrites are at the very bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/A2H3n/1/)

Move the `#contactinfo` div above the `#logoandtext`

HTML

```
<div id="sociallinks">/*Some thing here*/</div>
<div id="contactinfo">/*Some thing here*/</div>
<div id="logoandtext">/*Some thing here*/</div>
```

CSS

```
#logoandtext {
    margin: 0 140px;
    text-align: center;
} 
#contactinfo {
    float: right
}
```